# Struct Dinamico em Go LANG

Tags: golang

Tenho que fazer o struct abaixo de forma dinamica e nao tenho ideia de como fazer

```
{
      NE: [
        { lions: ['Zena', 'Maxwell', 'Faustino', 'Dee'] },
        { giraffes: ['Gracia', 'Antone', 'Vicky', 'Clay', 'Arron', 'Bernard'] },
      ],
      NW: [
        { tigers: ['Shu', 'Esther'] },
        { bears: ['Hiram', 'Edwardo', 'Milan'] },
        { elephants: ['Ilana', 'Orval', 'Bea', 'Jefferson'] },
      ],
      SE: [
        { penguins: ['Joe', 'Tad', 'Keri', 'Nicholas'] },
        { otters: ['Neville', 'Lloyd', 'Mercedes', 'Margherita'] },
      ],
      SW: [
        { frogs: ['Cathey', 'Annice'] },
        { snakes: ['Paulette', 'Bill'] },
      ],
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

Não sei se há uma definição de "dinamico", mas estou assumindo que considera "dinamico" porque a `key` de cada array muda.

---

Existem dois jeitos de fazer isso, o melhor é usar `map`:

```
type Animais map[string][]string

type Mundo struct {
    NE []Animais `json:"NE"`
    NW []Animais `json:"NW"`
    SE []Animais `json:"SE"`
    SW []Animais `json:"SW"`
}
```

Se você observar o JSON, pode notar que ele consiste de:

```
{ NE: [{<QUALQUER COISA>: [<QUALQUERCOISA>]}]
```

Portanto, isso é equivalente à fazer:

```
type X struct {
   NE []map[string][]string `json:"NE"`
}
```

Dentro do NE existe um array. Dentro deste array possui um objeto, cujo o index tem um nome aleatorio/dinamico, e o item desse array também é outro array de string.

---

Dessa forma pode fazer:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
)

type Animais map[string][]string

type Mundo struct {
    NE []Animais `json:"NE"`
    NW []Animais `json:"NW"`
    SE []Animais `json:"SE"`
    SW []Animais `json:"SW"`
}

func main() {
    data := []byte(`{"NE":[{"lions":["Zena","Maxwell","Faustino","Dee"]},{"giraffes":["Gracia","Antone","Vicky","Clay","Arron","Bernard"]}],"NW":[{"tigers":["Shu","Esther"]},{"bears":["Hiram","Edwardo","Milan"]},{"elephants":["Ilana","Orval","Bea","Jefferson"]}],"SE":[{"penguins":["Joe","Tad","Keri","Nicholas"]},{"otters":["Neville","Lloyd","Mercedes","Margherita"]}],"SW":[{"frogs":["Cathey","Annice"]},{"snakes":["Paulette","Bill"]}]}`)

    var resultado Mundo
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &resultado); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }



    // Faça qualquer coisa com o "resultado"
}
```

**[Teste isto no Playground.](https://go.dev/play/p/ba8H8FMYuSX)**